# Movie with weird Predator-looking creature that gets energy from a cigarette lighter

Tags: story-identification, alien-invasion

I watched this film years ago but I've forgot its name.

- In human form, creature was getting energy from a truck's cigarette lighter, using its tongue.
- Somehow other creatures were entering earth through a telescope dome (or was it a nuclear power plant?)
- Creatures look really weird. Jaws were like a Predators.

I'm certain it wasn't a cartoon movie. The creature was horror.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is definitely [Howard the Duck](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091225/). The car lighter scene was fairly disturbing but I guess they had to have a disturbing scene to make up for the scene with Lea Thompson in bed with a duck.

Comment: I thought the scene with her in bed with a 5 foot duck *was* the disturbing scene.

Comment: @Valorum well you can crop the duck out....errrr so I have heard.

Comment: So the duck phones down to reception and says "*Can you please send up a pack of condoms?*" and the receptionist says "*Sure. Would you like me to put those on your bill?*" and the duck says "***What do you think, I'm some kind of pervert?***"

Comment: heh heh I'll have to remember that one for the next time I need duck based humor

Comment: @Radhil the question was edited after I answered, then my answer was edited so all is well in this question now

Comment: Ah, sorry about that.

Comment: I am half tempted to edit in a vid of the bed scene but it wouldn't really add to the answer

Comment: I remember Steve Gerber supported the film, saying the stuff he saw while on the set was right in line with the tone of his book. I can look at the film and pinpoint, I think, exactly what scenes they were working on to give him that impression.  The bed scene was not one of them - "I'm'a find your feathered ass a JOB!" is.